# Storyboards, view controllers, and segmented controls

Tags: ios

I have a view controller in a storyboard with a segmented control.  The segmented control switches the view from three different types of displays.  To do this, I hide/unhide various view elements.  This works, but is difficult to edit in the Xcode storyboard editor.  I'd like to be able to have layers that I can turn on and off depending on the portion of the view I am working on.

Is there a way to do this?  Is there a better way?

**Update:**

I'm leaning towards creating the three views in separate xib files and loading them into the view controller view as needed.

Comment: What about using a tab bar controller?

Comment: Tab bar is already being used.  The segmented control switches between different views of the same object.

Comment: I would manually page a UIPageViewController, and disable user scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the three different ViewControllers in one Storyboard file and give each a Storyboard ID. Do not connect them with a segue. Then you drop a container view where you want them to be displayed and delete the automatically generated ViewController.

Then, for me the following code works:

```
-(void)loadSubviewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
{
    [self.subviewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.subviewController removeFromParentViewController];

    NSString* subviewIdentifier = [self.subviewIdentifiers objectAtIndex:idx];
    subviewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:subviewIdentifier];
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    subviewController.view.frame = frame;

    [self.view addSubview:self.subviewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.subviewController];
}
```

Here I assume that you have a property `subviewIdentifiers` which is an NSArray and an implicit map of your segmented control index to the Storyboard ID, and an `IBOutlet UIViewController* subviewController` which you link the container view to. Simply call this method from the segmented control action.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it has what I have come to see as a flaw.  Specifically, the call [self.view addSubview:self.subviewController.view] (see http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/).  I do think a kernel of a solution is here though: using a container view to switch custom UIViews, defined in their own xib files, in and out.

Comment: Good point, possibly you are right and one should avoid setting subviews manually like the code above does. However, your cited article is a bit outdated. It is a stated shift of paradigm of apple to allow for multiple view controllers per screen. And they provide the necessary tools in API and IB, that is view controller containment, which, I agree, I possibly do not use as intended. That said, I think, although it is possible to use Storyboard and XIB side by side, one should avoid that when possible.

Comment: Apologies, I must be missing something enormously obvious about the solution given. It states: > ...an IBOutlet UIViewController* subviewController which you link the container view to. ...but how can you link a container view (i.e. UIView) to an IBOutlet that's defined as a UIViewController? As it stands, I have a view controller, containing the container view. The IBOutlet is defined in my view controller code and so I have nothing to link it to. Confused :(